# How to show $\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)(\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i])|\xrightarrow[]{p}0$?

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence

**Question:** Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. and $\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$. I want to show
$$\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)(\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i])|\xrightarrow[]{p}0$$

**My thoughts:**

1. By definition I need to show
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr\left(\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)(\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i])|>\varepsilon\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr\left(\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)|\cdot|\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i]|>\varepsilon\right)=0$$
   for all $\varepsilon>0$;
2. Apparently $|\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i]|\xrightarrow[]{p}0$ by WLLN, so
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr\left(|\bar{X}_n-\mathbb{E}[X_i]|>\frac{\varepsilon}{\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)|}\right)=0$$
   for all $\varepsilon>0$

The problem is $\sup_{\theta\in(0,1)}|\log(\theta)|$ doesn't exist (I *think*), so I guess the above is not really correct. I wonder if there is a way to show the uniform convergence in question, or if there's no uniform convergence in the first place

**Some additional context**: I'm trying to show that the maximum-likelihood estimator of a logarithmic series distribution is consistent. In particular $X_i$ are i.i.d. with pmf
$$f(x;\theta)=\frac{-\theta^x}{x\log(1-\theta)}\quad\text{for}\quad x=1,2,\ldots$$ Since the MLE has no closed form, I'm reformulating the estimator as an M-estimator with criterion function
$$S_n(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\log(-\log(1-\theta))-X_i\log(\theta)\right)=\log(-\log(1-\theta))-\bar{X}_n\log(\theta)$$
Now you see in order to show consistency I need to show $S_n(\theta)$ converges in probability to $$S(\theta)=\mathbb{E}[\log(-\log(1-\theta))-X_i\log(\theta)]=\log(-\log(1-\theta))-\mathbb{E}[X_i]\log(\theta)$$
uniformly on $(0,1)$, thus the question. Have tried to appeal to the *Uniform Law of Large Numbers* but couldn't find a function to bound $|\log(-\log(1-\theta))-X_i\log(\theta)|$.

Comment: I don't really understand the "Motivation" part, but the thing you're trying to prove is definitely not true - except in very specific cases. Just imagine that the $\overline{X_n}\neq \mathsf{E} X$ almost surely - any continuous distribution - then your random variable on the LHS is almost surely $+\infty$!